# Htm to pdf converter with css

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, itext, wkhtmltopdf

I have used itextsharp.dll to convert the html to Pdf. It works fine only problem is it doesn't render the css in pdf. my code is as follows:

```
 string[] attachment;
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Certificate.pdf");
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            System.Text.StringBuilder ss = new System.Text.StringBuilder(CertificateHtml);
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(ss);
            HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
            StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
            Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A2, 7f, 7f, 7f, 0f);
            HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);


            string PdfName = "Certificate" + name;
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/DesktopModules/SterlingPlanet-SP_CheckOut/PDfCertificate/" + PdfName + ".pdf"), FileMode.Create));

            pdfDoc.Open();
            htmlparser.Parse(sr);

            pdfDoc.Close();
```

my css is as foolows

```
body {
    font-family: Conv_Californian FB,Arial;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#wrapper {
    background: url("../images/bg.jpg") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    height: 719px;
    margin: 25px auto 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 959px;
}
.wrapper_inner {
    color: White;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
.wrapper_inner h1 {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 65px;
    letter-spacing: 16px;
    padding-top: 38px;
    text-align: center;
}
.wrapper_inner h6 {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 17px;
    letter-spacing: 10px;
    margin: -53px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Is there any alternative to itextsharp.dll which can convert the html to pdf with the css or if there is any code i am missing that can render the css to the html.Kindly help.

Comment: The HTMLWorker class is deprecated and no longer supported. Instead you are encouraged to use the XMLWorker. http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/html/simpleparser/HTMLWorker.html

Comment: Does it not render ANY of the CSS, or just failing to render the background image: `background: url("../images/bg.jpg")`?

Answer (score 0):

When I have dealt with this in the past on secure servers, I have had to change the css reference before passing to the pdf converter.  Had similar problems with image references.

If the reference is to a secure server, the converter can't see it, and if it points to non-secure server, the secure page nags the user about unsecure content.

Answer (score 0):

Use inline css and size in pixel its not working in itextsharp html to pdf.

Comment: <div style="background: url("[Path]\Images\bg.jpg") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;">
       <div>
        <h1 >CERTIFICATE</h1>
        <h6 ></h6>
  </div>

Comment: Sir i am using the inline style like above but it still fail to load the following image.

Comment: use pdfpcell and use border for that and and cell.addelement() in add your parse html then it should be work sure. wait i'm giving you a example.